# Location of the MSDTC tab on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm following this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817066, I'm having trouble finding MSDTC tab on windows 7 can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDTC tab may need to be installed, according to [this answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764165/understanding-msdtc-in-windows/1831138#1831138):

> If it's not it can be installed with
>   the following command:
>
> `msdtc -install`
>
> You can configure the MSDTC service
>   using sc.exe. Set the service to start
>   automatically and start the service:
>
> `sc config msdtc start= auto`
>   `sc start msdtc`
>
> Note you will need administrator
>   privilege to perform the above.

Then you should be able to configure it in the *Component Services*.